# Trying to Train Cards Game with RL

Tags: reinforcement-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to train a card game called Callbreak I tried inputs like all the opponents discarded cards all hands everything a human can see and calculate with "common sense" I fed it to the Agent but it's not learning the way it should after 100M steps it learned as basic as any new/bad player will do in the game.
I have never tried to train a card game before so Idk what should I feed and how much to feed any help will be appreciated.

I have trained 100m+ steps before it will just keep repeating these drops and will never get more rewards.

config I am using is:

```
default:
trainer: ppo
batch_size: 1024
beta: 5.0e-3
buffer_size: 10240
epsilon: 0.2
hidden_units: 256
lambd: 0.95
learning_rate: 3.0e-4
learning_rate_schedule: linear
max_steps: 100.0e5
memory_size: 128
normalize: false
num_epoch: 3
num_layers: 3
time_horizon: 64
sequence_length: 64
summary_freq: 100000
use_recurrent: false
vis_encode_type: simple
reward_signals:
    extrinsic:
        strength: 1.0
        gamma: 0.99
```

Tensorboard
[image]

New Training Results

```
default:
trainer: ppo
batch_size: 1024
beta: 5.0e-3
buffer_size: 10240
epsilon: 0.2
hidden_units: 512
lambd: 0.95
learning_rate: 3.0e-4
learning_rate_schedule: linear
max_steps: 500.0e5
memory_size: 128
normalize: false
num_epoch: 3
num_layers: 3
time_horizon: 64
sequence_length: 64
summary_freq: 100000
use_recurrent: false
vis_encode_type: simple
reward_signals:
    extrinsic:
        strength: 1.0
        gamma: 0.99
    curiosity:
        strength: 0.02
        gamma: 0.99
        encoding_size: 256
```

[image]

[image]

[image]